# In Crystal FFI, how do I access a type in the C library?

Tags: sqlite, ffi, crystal-lang

The task I'm working on is to add support for [the `create_function` interface](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) to Crystal's SQLite binding: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal-sqlite3/issues/61

To access the parameters for a user-defined function, I need to access a C-style array (that is, a pointer to contiguous instances) of the `sqlite3_value` type, which if I'm not mistaken requires knowing the size of the type. But as far as I have found, there is no way to declare a Crystal type as an alias for a type defined in the C library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a pointer, no, you don't necessarily need to know its layout. For [opaque pointers](https://www.google.com/search?q=opaque+pointer) this pattern is common in Crystal:

```
type Sqlite3Context = Void*
type Sqlite3Value = Void*

fun sqlite3_create_function(
  [...]
  xFunc : (Sqlite3Context, Int, Sqlite3Value*) ->,
  [...]
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that it's two levels of pointers, not just a pointer to an array of structs. That actually solved my problem! Though I would still like to know if there is a way to get the size of a type defined in the C library.